# Transferring WordPress Instances

Tags: localhost, apache

I'm new to WordPress and have a question regarding taking a production instance of WordPress and creating a local instance. I'm helping a friend out who has a WordPress site live on the web and I would like to be able to create a local instance on my machine.

I was able to create the local instance, however all of the links are broken. They take me to the live site. Is this fixed by a WordPress configuration or an Apache Virtual Host?

Comment: If you have imported the database, then there two setting you need to change. Go to `phpMyAdmin -> ur database -> tabe - wp_options`. find two by option name `siteurl` & `home` . Change them to yours. It should work then.

Comment: See [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) in Codex.

Comment: so this isn't a matter of Virtual Hosting?

Answer (score 0):

You need change URLs in the complete database, not just in the two tables in wp_options.

See [WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool | Interconnect](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) and the docs at [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)